# Are they entitled to a hotel accommodation during transit?

Tags: transit, hotels, fra

My brother and his family, including 2 kids (all with Jordanian passports) are travelling from Georgia to Amman. During the flight, they will stop at Frankfurt airport for transit for 15 hours.

This is too long transit and I believe they are entitled to a hotel accommodation during transit

If so, who should they contact to get the hotel booking?

Comment: what airline are they flying?

Comment: Did they book the itinerary with 15 hours stopover initially or was that a result of changes made by the airlines? There is no right to a free hotel if they chose to book such itinerary, but some airlines may offer it to passengers based on the layover time and in some cases also based on which class they booked.

Answer (score 14):

If these are two separate tickets, the answer is definitely "NO"

If this is a single ticket, I assume its Lufthansa (since you are going though Frankfurt). This answer would be "highly unlikely". Maybe if you have a full fare first class ticket  you may be able to talk them into an accommodation.  There is only one airside hotel in Frankfurt https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/services/hotels/my-cloud-transit-hotel.html and I don't think they have an arrangement with Lufthansa. For any other hotel you need to leave the transit area which requires a Schengen Visa.

Things are little different if your itinerary was initially shorter and got padded due to a cancellation or schedule change, you may be able to score a hotel or meal voucher.

Comment: If the 15 hours delay was not planned, I believe that the "may score" is "will get" - because the plane is landing in the EU (it does not matter where it comes from, or where it is heading)

Comment: @WoJ: The "not planned" part in combination with "only one airside hotel" and "other hotels require a Schengen visa" together mean that Lufthansa might not be able to provide you with an effective hotel voucher. And not all airports have airside hotels.

Comment: @MSalters: right, I had the meal in mind. You are correct about the hotel (BTW it gets interesting when you have an unplanned overnight stop and cannot leave the terminal)